# How can I detect if the window really resized in IE8 standards mode?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

My site has many style sheets customized for varying screen widths. As the browser is resized, the `window.onresize` event checks that a resize actually took place by looking at `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. If it did, it turns on successively larger style sheets until scrollbars appear. Then, it turns them off in reverse order until scrollbars disappear. Scrollbars are detected by comparing `offsetWidth` to `scrollWidth`.

In IE8, two new problems confound detection of a resize. One, `onresize` fires whenever scrollbars appear or disappear, and two, `d.dE.clientWidth` reports the width without scrollbars, a break from IE7 and all other browsers. My site now frequently gets trapped in a loop in which the `onresize` logic activates a larger style sheet, which creates scrollbars, which then triggers another resize event that cannot be filtered out because the `clientWidth` has changed due to scrollbars appearing or disappearing. This would be a trivial fix if IE8 had something like `outerWidth` I could check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I had never dealt with scrollbar generation triggering onresize in any browser, I did not realize that checking d.dE.clientWidth was not a good verification, and in fact never did include the scrollbars. I now check d.dE.offsetWidth instead, and the repeated onresize events are filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost certainly aware of this - and it doesn't really answer your questions as it's forcing IE8 out of Standards Mode - but the quick fix would be to [force IE8 into IE7 mode using an HTTP header](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/06/10/introducing-ie-emulateie7.aspx).

Comment: This would be a good solution if IE7 compatibility mode didn't introduce border-collapse and hover regressions that are way too ugly to work around.